# How to change the color of status bar in sdk version under kitkat

Tags: java, android, toolbar, statusbar

I want to make statusbar's color as the color of toolbar. But i don't known how to do it in android sdk version under kitkat.
This is my toolbar layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/material_light_blue"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/info"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_title_size"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_sub_title_size"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It is my app theme:
    
        @color/white
        @color/white
        @dimen/text_sub_title_size

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Simple as that. KitKat is the first version that supported transparency of any kind in the status bar.

Comment: If there was, I would have mentioned it.